# Error creating bean with name 'configDataContextRefresher' [SpringBoot]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on a `Spring Boot` project. I got a weird error when I executed the command `mvn clean install`.
Below is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configDataContextRefresher' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher]: Factory method 'configDataContextRefresher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/ConfigurableBootstrapContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher]: Factory method 'configDataContextRefresher' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/ConfigurableBootstrapContext
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/ConfigurableBootstrapContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.ConfigurableBootstrapContext
```

I really do not understand what is `"configDataContextRefresher"`. I confirm that I don't use any configDataContextRefresher in my code. Besides, the whole error from the doesn't tell me where any locations where the error occurs on my code.

I've been trying to solve it for 2-3 hours and also fount nothing on the internet.

Please help. Thanks a lot !

---Edit---
More clues, I can do a **mvn spring-boot:run** to run the service. But I can't build the jar file.

Comment: Looks like the missing bean is from the Spring Cloud module. Is that on your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and it got resolved by adding inside properties tag in pom.xml this one,

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version> 
    <springcloud.version>Hoxton.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

and commented out the default properties tag which were coming.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a problem with a too old version of spring-boot. After changing the version to 2.6.2, the problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to inconsistancies (in your Pom.xml file) between Spring Boot version and the **properties** tag when you add some dependancies, like Eureka.

You can always make sure if you are using the currect settings in [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) checking the **Explore > Pom.xml** section

```
<parent>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.3</version>
 <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
 <java.version>17</java.version>
 <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was to update spring-boot-starter-parent artifactId version from:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Then the Eureka client registered without issues.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround by using

> -DskipTests

but I think there should be better solution to get rid of this weird error.